# Olympus E-M5 Mark II tethering SDK (Java, Windows)

Tags: olympus, tethering

On gPhoto page (http://www.gphoto.org/doc/remote/), there is Olympus E-M5 Mark 2 as supported camera. So tethering is supported by camera, but under Linux.

Is it possible to take images and live-view from my app in Windows? Is there any SDK for communication with camera for Windows and Java?

Thanks.

Comment: vtc b/c This is a programming question – it requests a Java SDK.

Comment: It requests a solution for a photographic purpose: using an Olympus E-M5 Mark II tethered to a Windows machine.

Comment: libgphoto2 is available for windows via [msys2](https://www.msys2.org/)

Answer (score 1):

The E-M5 Mk2 can be controlled from a Windows PC with the [Olympus Capture](https://app.olympus-imaging.com/olympuscapture/en/) software. Olympus did have an SDK for Four-Thirds DSLRs, but has not been released for their Micro Four-Thirds cameras. If you install USBPcap (I use it with Wireshark) you can capture and reverse-engineer the protocol. I haven't found any other instances of people attempting this.

Alternatively, as the gphoto2 developers have already implemented support, you could take a look at their source code. The actual camera access code is in their library libgphoto2, which can be found [here](https://github.com/gphoto/libgphoto2).